# Intersecting Graphs

Tags: calculus

Can someone please help me answer this question. I have no idea even where to get started.

> If $f(x)= 3\sin(2x)$ and $h(x)=k+2\cos(x)$ 
>   Find the range of values of $k$ for which $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ intersect at exactly two points.
>   Note: $k > 0$ and both $f(x)$ and $h(x)$ have domain $0 ≤ x ≤ 2\pi$

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you plot the two functions with k=0, you get a good clue.  Here's the plot:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3sin%282x%29+and+2cos%28x%29+from+0+to+2+pi

The key is to remember that we only care about the domain $x\in[0,2\pi]$.  We see from this plot that if we make k something like 2, then the graphs intersect at exactly two points, as shown here:  http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+3sin%282x%29+and+2+%2B+2cos%28x%29+from+0+to+2+pi